# Powershell cannot read hash

Tags: powershell, hash

I have powershell script that reads output from powershell command line and saves it into a hash.

When I try to get "sender-ip", the output is blank.

Below is the code

```
$args = (($args | % { $_ -join ", " }) -join " ")

foreach ($i in $args){
   $line_array+= $i.split(",")
}

foreach ($j in $line_array){
    $multi_array += ,@($j.split("="))
}

foreach ($k in $multi_array){
    $my_hash.add($k[0],$k[1])
    write-host $k
}

$Sender_IP = $my_hash.Get_Item("sender-ip")
Write-host 'sender-ip is' $Sender_IP
```

Here are the arguments passed into the script

```
script.ps1 Manager Last Name=Doe, discover-location=null, protocol=Clipboard, Resolution=null, file-owner=user, Employee Type=External Employee, endpoint-file-path=null, Title=null, discover-extraction-date=null, Sender-IP=10.10.10.10, Manager Business Unit=IT Services, Manager Phone=414-555-5555, Username=user, Division=Contractor, file-created-by=DOMAIN\user, file-owner-domain=DOMAIN
```

And this is the output

```
Manager Last Name Doe
 discover-location null
 protocol Clipboard
 Resolution null
 file-owner user
 Employee Type External Employee
 endpoint-file-path null
 Title null
 discover-extraction-date null
 Sender-IP 10.10.10.10
 Manager Business Unit IT Services
 Manager Phone 414-555-5555
 Username user
 Division Contractor
 file-created-by DOMAIN\user
 file-owner-domain DOMAIN
sender-ip is
```

The code seems correct, what is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you output the `$my_hash.Keys` property...

```
 file-created-by
 discover-extraction-date
 Manager Phone
 Employee Type
 endpoint-file-path
 file-owner-domain
 Title
 Manager Business Unit
 discover-location
 Sender-IP
 Username
 file-owner
 Resolution
Manager Last Name
 Division
 protocol
```

...you'll see that, due to the way you're parsing the command line arguments, all but one of the keys is prefixed with a space character.  The value you're looking for actually has key `" Sender-IP"`; there is no item with key `"Sender-IP"` in `$my_hash`.

To remove leading and trailing whitespace from all keys and values, you can use the [`String.Trim` instance method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/t97s7bs3.aspx) in your last `foreach` loop like this...

```
foreach ($k in $multi_array) {
    $key = $k[0].Trim()
    $value = $k[1].Trim()

    $my_hash.add($key, $value)
    write-host $key $value
}
```